# Сохранение blob файла на диск с базы данных

Tags: c#, oracle, excel, blob

Как сохранить файл из базы данных oracle ? Файл хранится как blob . 
Файл соответственно Excel.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ну как правило `blob`-файл это простой бинарник=>

1. Считываешь его простым запросом
2. Результатом запроса скорее всего будет массив байт(или что-то иное содержащие его если это реализовано в провайдере), который нужно будет пульнуть в `File.WriteAllBytes` и сохранить с нужным расширением

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090873/4244707) описано почти тоже самое, что я описал.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос уже решён)